# 'Git Command Not found' in the custom action for SourceTree

Tags: git

When I add a sh file to SourceTree's custom action function, the error message is:

```
git: command not found
```

But when I go to terminal to use git command, it exists. If I add the path to Git in my sh file, it works.

How to run my script without entering full path to git?

`git archive --output=archive-$1.tar $1 $(git diff-tree -r --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT $1)`

Why does source tree demand full path to Git?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why I can not run without increasing the path to git command?

Comment: hmm.. ->superuser, anyways?

Comment: @xuan: most probably, your `SourceTree` as the PATH environment variable set differently than your user account. Write `echo $PATH`(linux) or `echo %PATH%`(windows) in your console and also in some another custom action, and then compare the results. I bet they will differ much.

Comment: There isn't just one copy of `PATH`.  Every running program has its own copy of all the environment variables.  Whatever you're using to start SourceTree isn't passing along the `PATH` value you want.

Comment: thanks everyone tell me about `$path`.
I later looked at `~/.Profile` of this file,

my path is `PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin`,

then me change the content is `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin`,

and add `source ~/.profile` to the `sh` file,  then it solves.

Comment: @xuan please add an official Answer if that comment solves your question!

Answer (score 1):

SourceTree custom actions do not have the same $PATH set as when using Terminal.

```
echo $PATH
```

SourceTree custom action bash script:

> /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

macOS terminal:

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

change the PATH variable to use the macOS default instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

hub sync
```

There may be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

When opening up the terminal, the command `bash --login -i` appears briefly. If you add that to your Custom Action, it gets the same path that you'd get with the terminal.

Setup the custom action as follows:

- Script to run: Select bash.exe from the browse window, it might be in:

  `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree\git_local\bin\bash.exe`
- Parameters: `--login -i c:\path_to_script\script.sh`
- Check Show Full Output and Run command silently to see the output in the action box, uncheck Show Full Output to hide it unless clicked while running.

It may be useful to add the following to the script to pause the screen to see any error messages (with Open in an Separate Window checked and run silently unchecked, I believe)

`read -p "Press [Enter] key to continue..."`